# Преобразовать словарь словарей в словарь со списками на python

Tags: python, list, dict

У меня есть словарь со словарями, который показывает наличие фруктов определенного цвета:

```py
dict1 = {
     'Apple': {'Green': True, 'Red': False}, 
     'Melon': {'Yellow': False}, 
     'Orange': {'Red': True, 'Green': False, 'Yellow': True},
     'Banana': {'Yellow': True}
     }
```

его нужно преобразовать в словарь со списками такого формата:

```py
list1 = {
     'Apple': ['Green'], 
     'Melon': ['NO_FRUITS'], 
     'Orange': ['Red', 'Yellow'],
     'Banana': ['Yellow']}
```

То есть ключи словаря - фрукты, а значение ключей - списки с наличием видов этого фрукта.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
dict1 = {
    'Apple': {'Green': True, 'Red': False}, 
    'Melon': {'Yellow': False}, 
    'Orange': {'Red': True, 'Green': False, 'Yellow': True},
    'Banana': {'Yellow': True}
}

list1 = {
    k: [n for n, f in d.items() if f] or ['NO_FRUITS']
    for k, d in dict1.items()
}

print(list1)
```

> ```
> {'Apple': ['Green'], 'Melon': ['NO_FRUITS'], 'Orange': ['Red', 'Yellow'], 'Banana': ['Yellow']}
> ```

**P.S.** Зачем `['NO_FRUITS']`? Пустой список не будет удобнее?

Answer (score 2):

Решил вашу проблему самым примитивным способом. Комментарии указал

```
from pprint import pprint

dict1 = {
    'Apple': {'Green': True, 'Red': False},
    'Melon': {'Yellow': False},
    'Orange': {'Red': True, 'Green': False, 'Yellow': True},
    'Banana': {'Yellow': True}
}
list1 = dict()

# Проходимся циклом по ключам словаря dict1
for fruit in dict1:
    # Создаем пустой список в новом словаре, чтобы добавлять туда фрукты в наличии 
    list1[fruit] = []
    # Проходимся циклом по всем видам фруктов
    for kind in dict1[fruit]:
        # Если продукт в наличии, добавляем в список по ключу искомого словаря
        if dict1[fruit][kind]:
            list1[fruit].append(kind)
    # Если после всех опреаций список остается пустым, отмечаем это добавлением строки "NO_FRUITS" 
    if not list1[fruit]:
        list1[fruit].append("NO_FRUITS")

pprint(list1)
```

Вывод:

```
{'Apple': ['Green'],
 'Banana': ['Yellow'],
 'Melon': ['NO_FRUITS'],
 'Orange': ['Red', 'Yellow']}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
res = {}
for k in dict1:
    res[k]=[j for j in dict1[k].keys() if dict1[k][j]] or ["No fruits"]

print(res)
```

> {'Apple': ['Green'], 'Melon': ['No fruits'], 'Orange': ['Red', 'Yellow'], 'Banana': ['Yellow']}

Comment: Мне тут не давно доказывали, что в  `for j in dict1[k].keys()`  keys() использовать, не по питонячьи :)

Answer (score 1):

Можете сделать так:

```py
dict1 = {
     'Apple': {'Green': True, 'Red': False}, 
     'Melon': {'Yellow': False}, 
     'Orange': {'Red': True, 'Green': False, 'Yellow': True},
     'Banana': {'Yellow': True}
}

list1 = {}

for key in dict1:
    array = []
    for fruit in dict1[key]:
        if dict1[key][fruit] == True:
            array.append(fruit)
    if len(array) == 0:
        array.append('NO_FRUITS')
    list1[key] = array

print(list1)
```

Вывод:

```py
{'Apple': ['Green'], 'Melon': ['NO_FRUITS'], 'Orange': ['Red', 'Yellow'], 'Banana': ['Yellow']}
```

Comment: `== True` можно убрать, а `len(array) == 0` заменить на `not array`.

Comment: Ну, я с JavaScript так привык. Что ж поделать )

Comment: В JavaScript надо писать `== true`? Не знал.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Не обязательно, но можно. Лично мне краткость иногда мешает.

Comment: Тогда уж так `== true == true`. Так краткость ещё меньше мешает.

Comment: Вот это сарказм

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1 = {
     'Apple': {'Green': True, 'Red': False}, 
     'Melon': {'Yellow': False}, 
     'Orange': {'Red': True, 'Green': False, 'Yellow': True},
     'Banana': {'Yellow': True}
     }


list1 = {
    key: list(filter(inner.get, inner))
    for key, inner in dict1.items()
}
```

Как вам уже сказали, с пустым списком будет удобнее.